# Is it bad style to supply boolean in find()?

Tags: c++, iterator, find

In "Accelerated C++: Practical Programming by Example", Chapter 6.1.3 is an example for the `find()` from the "algorithm" library:

We want to check if a `char` is in a string:

```
bool find_char(char c){
    string str = "asdf";
    return find(str.begin(), str.end(), c) != str.end();
}
```

Then, there is an explanation of `find()`:

> It is similar to find_if, except that instead of calling a predicate, it looks for the specific value given as its third argument. As with find_if, if the value that we want is present, the function returns an iterator denoting the first occurrence of the value in the given sequence. **If the value is not found, then find returns its second argument.**

This left me wondering why we don't use the much shorter and cleaner version:

```
bool find_char(char c){
    string str = "asdf";
    return find(str.begin(), false, c); //does not compile, see Top Answer
}
```

Is this considered bad style? Is there a problem with that code?

Comment: Think about how `find` would know where to terminate the search...

Comment: [`std::any_of`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/all_any_none_of) is what you would use if you just want to check the existance of an element.  `std::find` will also tell you *where* the element was found.

Comment: You are right, that would actually be a better function!

Comment: JFYI: `char` is a reserved keyword.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The problem is that the second argument is not only the value which is returned when the needle is not found in the haystack, the second argument is also the (pointer or iterator to) the end of the haystack itself.  Your example with `false` as the second argument to `std::find` will not compile, as `false` is no kind of iterator, and certainly is not comparable or compatible in any way with `std::string::begin()`, much less forming the end of a range.

Answer (score 2):

Your variant is wrong because your function will always return true due to the fact that the second iterator is not equal to zero (and it indeed is not equal to zero). Function find returns an iterator (either of the found value or the last iterator of the range) not a bool value.

Answer (score 0):

Well, the primary purpose of `std::find` is to give you the iterator for the element that has been *found*, in case it has been found. So, this is why `std::find` returns an iterator.

The situation when the element has not been found is a special case, which is indicated by the second argument being returned as the result.

If `std::find` returned `bool`, it would not be able to tell us where it found the target data. You don't care about it in your case, but in may (or most) other cases we do.